# htaccess www well in home page but not in other pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file content

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]



# Remove index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]




# Redirect Http To Https
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]



# Redirect Non Www To Www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

my `example.com` redirected well to `www.example.com` (Not problem)

my problem when I go to other pages like

`example.com/page1/test` redirected to `www.example.com`

(That my problem) I need it redirect me to `www.example.com/page1/test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directives are in the wrong order. You need to put your canonical redirects *before* the front-controller - at the top of the file.

By placing the redirects at the end they are simply never going to get processed for anything other than static files/directories since everything else is routed to `index.php`.

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is also incorrect since you are unconditionally prefixing with the www subdomain.

Also, no need to repeat `RewriteEngine` throughout the file.

In other words, arrange your directives like this (assuming you are not intending to implement HSTS):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect Non Www To Www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Http To Https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It is more efficient to use a regex like `^` to simply be successful for every URL, rather than `.*` that needs to traverse the entire URL-path - since you are not capturing this.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Preferably test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.